# Firefox-specific issue encountered when using page.setInputFiles() in Playwright test

Tags: javascript, firefox, playwright

The problem arises when attempting to use the page.setInputFiles() method in a Playwright test specifically on the Firefox browser via GitHub Actions.Tests carried out on local host have 0 issues. While the code functions smoothly on Chrome and Safari, it encounters an error or unexpected behavior when interacting with file input elements on Firefox.

Here is my code:

```
import { test } from '@playwright/test'

test('Upload', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(`TestURL/login`)
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Ok, accept all' }).click()
  await page.getByLabel('Email address').fill(`userEmail`)
  await page.getByLabel('Password').fill(`${user Pass}`)
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Log In', exact: true }).click()
  await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Create' }).click()
  await page.getByText('Upload new music').click()

  const metaData = {
    title: 'Mocked Song Title',
    artist: 'Mocked Song Artist',
    album: 'Mocked Song Album',
    picture: {
      mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
      buffer: Buffer.from(
        'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
        'base64'
      ),
    },
  }
  const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1024 * 1024, 'a')
  const fileContent = Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from('ID3'),
    Buffer.from([4, 0, 0, 0]),
    Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(metaData)),
    buffer,
  ])
  const mockedFilePath = './mockedFile.mp3'
  require('fs').writeFileSync(mockedFilePath, fileContent)

  await page
    .locator('div')
    .filter({ hasText: 'Click to upload music or drag and dropMP3' })
    .nth(1)
    .click()
  await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', mockedFilePath)
  await page.locator('textarea').click()
  await page.locator('textarea').fill('Test upload')
  await page.locator('div').filter({ hasText: 'Change image' }).nth(1).click()
  await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', {
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'mockedImage.jpg',
    buffer: Buffer.from(
      'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
      'base64'
    ),
  })
  await page.getByLabel('Title', { exact: true }).click()
  await page.getByLabel('Title', { exact: true }).fill('mocked song')
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Upload music' }).click()
  await page.getByText('Song uploaded successfully').click()
})
```

When attempting to use the page.setInputFiles() method in a Playwright test on Firefox, I expected the file to be successfully uploaded to the file input element on the page. I tested the code on Chrome and Safari, where it worked without any issues. However, when running the test on Firefox, an error or unexpected behavior occurred.

I tried updating both the Playwright library and Firefox to their latest versions, ensuring compatibility between the two. I also verified that the file input selector (input[type="file"]) accurately targeted the correct element on the page. Additionally, I tested with different file inputs to rule out any issues specific to the file being used.

Despite these efforts, the problem persisted. The error or unexpected behavior specifically occurred when executing the page.setInputFiles() method on Firefox, preventing the successful upload of files and causing the test to fail

Here is Playwright Test Report:

```
 1) [firefox] › upload.spec.ts:3:5 › Upload ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────

frame.setInputFiles: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('input[type="file"]')
============================================================

  37 |     .nth(1)
  38 |     .click()
> 39 |   await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', mockedFilePath)
     |   ^
  40 |   await page.locator('textarea').click()
  41 |   await page.locator('textarea').fill('Test upload')
  42 |   await page.locator('div').filter({ hasText: 'Change image' }).nth(1).click()


Retry #1 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

frame.setInputFiles: Target page, context or browser has been closed

  37 |     .nth(1)
  38 |     .click()
> 39 |   await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', mockedFilePath)
     |   ^
  40 |   await page.locator('textarea').click()
  41 |   await page.locator('textarea').fill('Test upload')
  42 |   await page.locator('div').filter({ hasText: 'Change image' }).nth(1).click()



Retry #2 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

frame.setInputFiles: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('input[type="file"]')
============================================================

  37 |     .nth(1)
  38 |     .click()
> 39 |   await page.setInputFiles('input[type="file"]', mockedFilePath)
     |   ^
  40 |   await page.locator('textarea').click()
  41 |   await page.locator('textarea').fill('Test upload')
  42 |   await page.locator('div').filter({ hasText: 'Change image' }).nth(1).click()
```

Comment: `an error or unexpected behavior occurred` is that the exact error and the total information you have about the error?

Comment: [This test](https://github.com/kblok/playwright-troubleshooting/blob/main/tests/so-76261082.spec.ts) it's [working for me in Firefox](https://github.com/kblok/playwright-troubleshooting/actions/runs/4992042375/jobs/8939383848)

Comment: @hardkoded yes but problem occurs in GitHub Action during pushing commit to repository

Comment: The second link is a github action result

Comment: I am having the same problem, but with GitLab CI. I get the error `Target page, context or browser has been closed`, only with Firefox, and it works when running the tests locally. And compared to OP, I'm using [Locator.setInputFiles](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-set-input-files) instead of [Page.setInputFiles](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-set-input-files).